# Efficiently searching an instance or its children for a specific type

Tags: c#

I have the following conditional flow and I'd like some comments about it:

```
bool IsPositive(object sender)
{
  if (!(sender is SymbolIcon symbolIcon))
  {
    if (sender is ContentControl content && content.Content is SymbolIcon i)
      symbolIcon = i;
    else if (sender is Viewbox viewBox && viewBox.Child is SymbolIcon si)
      symbolIcon = si;
    else
      throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not extract icon from '{sender}'.");
  }

  return symbolIcon.Symbol == Symbol.Add;
}
```

The purpose of this code is to determine if the [`Symbol`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol) of a [`SymbolIcon`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon) which can exist in the following 3 ways in `sender`, is `Symbol.Add`:

- Could be `sender` itself
- `sender` is a `Button` with `SymbolIcon` as its content
- `sender` is a `ViewBox` with `SymbolIcon` as its content

But the question is not about `SymbolIcon` or any other technology, it's about C#. The question is if there would be a better way to write this code.

P.S. C# version is 7.3.

Comment: Which framework is this? WPF, WinForms, asp.net...?

Comment: @t3chb0t
The truth is that it doesn't matter. The question is about C#. `SymolIcon` doesn't matter here either. Including `SymbolIcon` in the title is not justified.

Comment: I've updated the title to drop the C# tag which is automatically added to search results on external sites and represented in the UI here through the [tag] mechanism. I also dropped the "How To" part of the title which is likely to attract close-votes, since asking how to accomplish a thing (i.e. changing what the code does) is not on-topic on this site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be heavily simplified using pattern matching:

```
bool IsPositive(object sender)
{
  switch (sender)
  {
    case SymbolIcon icon:
      return icon.Symbol == Symbol.Add;
    case ContentControl c when c.Content is SymbolIcon icon:
      return icon.Symbol == Symbol.Add;
    case ViewBox v when v.Child is SymbolIcon icon:
      return icon.Symbol == Symbol.Add;
  }
  throw new InvalidOperationException([..]);
}
```

Notice the repetition in the case blocks? At this point one might be tempted to try and merge these, but you won't be able to. Even the Roslyn 2.0 compiler doesn't allow you to declare a  variable with the same name in the same scope twice.

That said, something here is weird and dangerous. The name `sender` implies that you're doing some event processing here.
That in turn implies that you have the same event handler for multiple different components, otherwise how will you end up putting many different components into the same `IsPositive` method.

The code I presented above might be more succinct (and use the latest fancy gimmicks), but it still smells.

The **correct** solution here is to have distinct event handlers for the separate components. That way you don't need to deal with any unexpected layouts in that method. It also makes dealing with the SymbolIcon very easy.

**But wait: This thing shows an underlying issue with how your program is designed.**

As it stands, you're using the UI controls to **store business logic state**. Don't do that. Instead use proper MVC / MVVM concern separation. Don't store booleans in Symbols. Instead expose booleans from your model and convert them using a custom  converter to set your SymbolIcons from that.

Comment: The code presented has been tested with a simplified example on dotnetfiddle using the Roslyn 2.0 compiler (as the .NET4.5 compiler refused to deal with pattern matching case blocks).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I'm using MVVM. But the VM exposes a numeric property and I'm using this in view code-behind to `++`/`--` the numeric property in the VM.

Comment: @Shimmy _I'm using MVVM._ + _The truth is that it doesn't matter._ - yeah, we just saw that how it doesn't matter...

Comment: Doesn't matter indeed. Question was solely about C#.